# How to move the text pointer from one field to another in java

Tags: java, javafx

Iam using javafx to implement a calculator ... my calculator's design should be from Hewlett-Packard from seventies .. I have two text fields , in each text field I insert a number ... When I put a number in first text field so should I press ENTER in my calculator to move the text pointer to next text field to put anther number in it ... The problem that I do not know how to move the text pointer to the next text field when I press ENTER ... Here is my code for button Enter :

```
TextField text1 = new TextField();
TextField text2 = new TextField();
Button Enter = new Button("ENTER");
Enter.setLayoutX(140);
Enter.setLayoutY(270);
Robot robot = new Robot();


    Enter.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {


            if (event.getSource() == Enter) {
                robot.mouseMove(250,150); // (250,150) is the position of the second text field
            }
        }

    });
```

The problem with this code that when I press ENTER then my mouse pointer moves to
(250,150) but not my text pointer ...
How to move the text pointer instead of mouse pointer?
thank you

EDIT :

```
TextField text1 = new TextField();
TextField text2 = new TextField();
TextField text3 = new TextField();
Button Enter = new Button("ENTER");
Enter.setLayoutX(140);
Enter.setLayoutY(270);


    Enter.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {


            if (event.getSource() == Enter) {
                if (!text1.requestFocus() || text2.requestFocus()) {
                text3.requestFocus();
              } 
            }
        }

    });
```

Comment: You can requestFocus() on the next element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just request focus on the next element.

```
enter.setOnAction( event -> {
    if(text1.isFocused()) {
       text2.requestFocus();
    } else if(text2.isFocused()) {
       text3.requestFocus();
    }
});
```

You can do the same in Java 7 or prior versions using :

```
enter.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
        text2.requestFocus();
    }
});
```

Comment: That is lambda expression in java 8. Edited the answer with more information.

Comment: if I have three text fields , text1 text2 and text3 ... if text pointer is in text2 so If I press Enter so should I move to text3  .. How do I do that? Can I use some if statements ... please look at EDIT

Comment: @ramialsaiad Edited the answer.